# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate is not updating the document, instead it is creating a new one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Node, Express, and MongoDB/Mongoose for my backend. I have this `PUT` route set up:

```
//where id is the unique id of the review, not the movie
router.put('/update/:id', [jsonParser, jwtAuth], (req, res) => {
    Review.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id,
        { $set: { ...req.body } }, { new: true })
        .then(review => {
            console.log(review);
            res.status(203).json(review);
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({message: err}));
});
```

Using Postman upon creating a new document on my `POST` route, the response is the following:

```
{
    "genre_ids": [
        "28"
    ],
    "_id": "5ce112d0aeadc44ea0ea7bb0",
    "movieId": 447404,
    "title": "Pokemon Detective Pikachu",
    "poster_path": "/wgQ7APnFpf1TuviKHXeEe3KnsTV.jpg",
    "reviewer": "5cda5d08f3a74252c83b4a63",
    "reviewTitle": "the best",
    "reviewText": "new review",
    "reviewScore": 5,
    "__v": 0
}
```

Using Postman when I try to update the following document on this url
`.../review/update/5ce112d0aeadc44ea0ea7bb0` where the id the is taken from _id of the `POST` response above. 
I make a very simple change in the `PUT` request just to change the score.

```
{
    "reviewScore": 1
}
```

I then get the following response from the `PUT` route.

```
{
    "genre_ids": [
        "28"
    ],
    "_id": "5ce089116b537a08403ed25f",
    "movieId": 447404,
    "title": "Pokemon Detective Pikachu",
    "poster_path": "/wgQ7APnFpf1TuviKHXeEe3KnsTV.jpg",
    "reviewer": "5ce0882d90b63613700b066a",
    "reviewTitle": "the best",
    "reviewText": "updated review",
    "reviewScore": 1,
    "__v": 0
}
```

You can see that in the `PUT` request response, both the `_id` and `reviewer` have changed. In fact, it has created a new document for another user, instead of updating the original document. If I login to the account belonging to `_id` that's given from the `PUT` response, it does indeed show that a new document was created for that account and not updated the document for the other/original account.

Why is this happening? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the conditions as an object.

```
router.put('/update/:id', 
    [jsonParser, jwtAuth], 
    (req, res) =>{
         Review.findOneAndUpdate({'_id' :req.params.id}, { $set: { ...req.body } }, { new: true })
        .then(review => { console.log(review);
         res.status(203).json(review); 
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({message: err}));
    }
);
```

Or if you want to directly use the `id` like in your code, just replace `findOneAndUpdate` to `findByIdAndUpdate`.

Check out [Mongoose Query API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model)